# Model block not significant but interaction dummie is, should I interpret it?

Tags: logistic, binary-data

Im doing a binary logistic regression with various blocks.

I got 2 interactions.

Of 1 the block is not significant in total, but some dummie combinations of the interaction are.
Should I still interpret them?

Answer (score 0):

No.

Suppose you have an interaction between two dummy variables with 5 and 4 levels respectively. Then there are 20 levels in the interaction. Under the null hypothesis (the features are totally unrelated to the target), you would expect to see on average one out of these 20 features reach significance at the 0.05 level (because that's what a p-value is). Under those circumstances it would be a mistake for the analyst to interpret the lone significant interaction. The whole point of block significance tests is to fix this shortcoming of the individual significance test.

As usual, the most vivid example of this phenomenon was provided by [xkcd](http://xkcd.com/882/):

[image: Green jelly beans cause acne]